# Is there a way to edit the origin point of a brush?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was playing around with brushes in photoshop and was wondering if it is possible to adjust the position of the origin point within a brush shape.

As far as I know the origin of a brush tip shape is always in the center of a brush tip shape. However in certain cases it would be useful if you were able to move it to a different position (image 1), for example if you want to use Shape Dynamics with Angle Jitter and set the Control to "Direction".
If I draw a circle with these settings the brush is overlaying itself. However, if I were able to edit the origin point I could avoid this. (see image 2).

[image: Brush tip position]

[image: Drawing a circle]

Comment: As far as I know, No thats not possible.

Comment: Okay, I figured out a work around solution that kinda works. One thing you can do is add a single pixel in the opposite direction of the brush tip shape before you define it as a "Brush Preset". This way you can more or less control where the origin point of the brush is going to be. Still, you have to eyeball the whole thing which doesn't really make it easy to achieve the desired effect and requires a lot of trial and error...